# Can you call PoW 2f resilient?

Tags: consensus, byzantine-fault-tolerance

Can you call PoW 2f resilient if all nodes would have same hash power?
PoW is called eventually consistence. Even in an asynchronous network.

The only attack possible is 51% attack. Further, there is the selfish-mining issue.

At the end, PoW tolerates up to 50% malicious nodes, if the hash power would be the same? PBFT is only 3f+1 resilient.

Comment: related: [PoW 51% attack vs. BFT 1/3 attack?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/77601/pow-51-attack-vs-bft-1-3-attack?rq=1)